# How to show a button on Customer Form only in view mode?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I created a button to redirect to an external page on the customer form on NetSuite through SuiteScript and it shows only in EDIT mode, but I want to show it only in VIEW mode. What can I do to fix it?

I tried some script lines but didn't work. The button is working properly redirecting to the external page, the problem is only about showing in the correct place, which is ONLY on VIEW mode.

Comment: What do you want the button to do when it's pressed ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add context type in the user event script beforeLoad(context),
just add this line in the before load function at top.

Note- in Function if you using beforeLoad(context) then use **context** else use **sriptContext**.

```
if (sriptContext.type !== sriptContext.UserEventType.VIEW)
                return;
```

It will work.
Thanks.

Comment: Why not just if (sriptContext.type === sriptContext.UserEventType.VIEW). I think guard clause is not needed for that.

Comment: For simple line code I said , even he can use whole code in if also.

Comment: Yeah that is true but for some it might be confusing that is why I suggested simple if condition.

Comment: I have suggested the perfect logic that we should use as a good coder. I hope you may understand , we are here to be good /pro level coder.